# Refresh query data in LWC every X seconds

Tags: lightning-web-components, wire

I want to refresh my Apex every X seconds from my LWC component.

I have a wired function in my component:

```
initialized;
wiredData;

@wire(getChartData)
chartData(result) {

    this.wiredData = result;

    if (result.data) {
        if (!this.initialized) {
            console.log('Initializing Chart!');
            this.initialized = true;
            
            // Do setup stuff here

            //Invoke a setInterval to rerun this wired method and goto next block
            setInterval(refreshApex(this.wiredData), 5 * 1000);
 
        }
        else {
            console.log('Updating Chart!')
            this.chart.update();
        }
    }
    else if (result.error) {
        console.log('Error in wire function getChartData!');
        console.log(result.error);
    }
}
```

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to call the return value of `refreshApex`, which is a Promise. This won't work the way you expect. You need to use a function, so one of any of the following should work.

---

`Function.prototype.bind` makes a function with bound parameters. Perfect for this scenario.

```
setInterval(refreshApex.bind(this, this.wiredData), 5e3);
```

---

An [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) remembers what `this` is, and is definitely preferred over the normal `function()` whenever you can.

```
setInterval(()=>refreshApex(this.wiredData), 5e3)
```

---

You can also just set another function to do the work.

```
doRefresh() {
  refreshApex(this.wiredData);
}
// ... in your wire handler
setInterval(this.doRefresh, 5e3);
```

Notice how we do *not* use parentheses to specify parameters, because this would actually call the method, which isn't what we want.

`setInterval`'s first parameter should be some kind of [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function). If it is not, you're doing something wrong. If you're ever not sure, a handy trick is to check:

```
let x = someExpression;
console.log(x instanceof Function); // this will be true if it is.
```

If you get anything else, you know you've done something wrong. For example:

```
let x = refreshApex(this.wiredData);
console.log(x instanceof Function); // this is false, it is a Promise.
```

---

Finally, a word of caution. Always store the value from `setInterval` and call `clearInterval` before attempting to set a new one.

```
clearInterval(this.timerId);
this.timerId = setInterval(...);
```

Also clear the interval in the `disconnectedCallback`.

If you don't, your method will continue to run every five seconds each time the wire method is called, and you'll end up with a [memory leak](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) and degraded performance.